# How to send http request and response in titanium alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I have created a mobile app which contains the submit form. On click of submit I need hit the URL and pass the form values in the URL also need to get the response message. How can I do that? Can any one suggest some blogs or tutorials on the same.

Also I need to perform the above operation on Android, IOS and Windows platform. Is it possible to do above functionality on three platforms?

If any limitations on any platform, Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Link:-

[Check it out:-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773261/how-we-get-and-post-api-in-titanium-alloy/26773461#26773461)

if you found any issue regarding this please let me know

Spartacus thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will the code works for all three platforms (Android , IOS and Windows) ?

Comment: But the following titanium document says that, The windows sdk doesn't support http request. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Getting_Started_with_the_Windows_8_SDK. What is the resin for it

Comment: yaa..i just use this in android and ios

Comment: Then any idea about windows?